# Utile vulnerability

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

There's a known vulnerability for utile npm module, version 0.3.0(or lower), allows to extract sensitive data from uninitialized memory or to cause a DoS by passing in a large number, in setups where typed user input can be passed (e.g. from JSON), see https://hackerone.com/reports/321701

I have a node.js project that leverage the utile npm module, the dependencies in package-lock.json is below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYqdz.png)

```
"utile": {
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/-/utile-0.2.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-kwyI6ZCY1iIINMNWy9mncFItkNc=",
  "dev": true,
  "requires": {
    "async": "~0.2.9",
    "deep-equal": "*",
    "i": "0.3.x",
    "mkdirp": "0.x.x",
    "ncp": "0.4.x",
    "rimraf": "2.x.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": {
      "version": "0.2.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-trvgsGdLnXGXCMo43owjfLUmw9E=",
      "dev": true
    },
    "mkdirp": {
      "version": "0.5.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-NKmAlESf6jMGym1++R0Ra7wvhV+wFW63FaSOFPwRahvea0gMUcGUhVeAg/0BC0wiv9ih5NYPB1Wn1UEI1/L+xQ==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "minimist": "^1.2.5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is part code in package-lock.json file which include utile module with 2 dependencies async and mkdirp.

Does somebody happen to run into vulnerability and want to remove the vulnerability? Is there a replacement package for utile npm module or asncy/mkdirp that we can leverage instead of using utile module?

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/flatiron/utile/issues/28) on the utile GitHub, but the package looks abandoned... Its last commit was in 2014, and the issue was opened in 2018. I don't think a fix is coming unless you want to fork the repository and fix it yourself.

Comment: Wall actually, it looks like there's [an existing PR](https://github.com/flatiron/utile/pull/29) that apparently fixes it, but it's never been merged.

Comment: Hi @zcoop98, thanks for replying. I'm not going to fix it. I just want to find a replacement for utile that I can remove the utile module from my project to avoid this vulnerability. But I can't find a replacement for it.